# Send visiters to google search if page not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On my website, I want to send visiters to google search if they enter a page that does not exist.

forexample if they enter

```
 www.example.com/existing_page
```

then the page should be served,

but if they enter a page

```
   www.example.com/non_existing_page
```

then I want to send them to

```
 www.google.com/search.
```

How can I impliment this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your /.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://www.google.com/search?q=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```